# Retrieve the value of a selected ui:outputText in an iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I'm trying to retrieve the value of ui:outputText when selected

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
 <div class="card card-body" onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}">
  <ui:outputText aura:id="acntId" value="{!account.Id}" class="accountId"/>
 </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

My controller has

```
var accountId = component.find("acntId").get("v.value");
```

I'm having an 'Uncaught error in $A.run() : component.find(...).get is not a function'

Comment: can you post your complete js controller code ?

Comment: var accountId = component.find("acntId").get("v.value");                  alert(myLabel);

Comment: I'm betting component.find("acntId") is an array of all the outputTexts, you have the proper solution below, just fyi that find can return an array if there are multiple components with the same aura:id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick!

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
 <div class="card card-body">
  <ui:outputText value="{!account.Id}" click="{!c.navigateToRecord}"/>
 </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller:

```
var src = event.getSource();
var accountName = src.get("v.value");
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be that you are giving the same id to multiple outputTexts.

What you could do instead is move move the onclick event handler from the div onto the ui:outputText:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
 <div class="card card-body" >
  <ui:outputText aura:id="acntId" value="{!account.Id}" class="accountId" click="c.navigateToRecord" />
 </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Then in the controller you can get the accountId like this:

```
var accountId = event.getSource().get("v.value");
```

Comment: yes. it works outside the iteration. do you know any work around on retrieving the id of a selected item on iteration?

Comment: although it displays the correct output inside of the iteration. i cant seem to retrieve its value.

Comment: @cloudforce Are you trying to get the value of one particular outputText, or did you want to get all of them?

Comment: one particular outputText of the selected item in the aura:iteration